# Display a/b Type of Information Django/Crispy Forms

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I have a model that contains multiple fields which are rendered with a crispy model. Now, I want to display information of the type foo/bar in that form, looking like the other fields. bar being a number set in my model instance, foo being the number of objects from a different model. Idea: I found foo entries of the expected bar.

I struggle to model this in crispy forms: Do I either have a new CharField in my Model and have a weird way updating it? Or do I have to put these infos together in crispy forms?

If foo != bar, this is an information about a potential error occuring.

Any ideas/concepts you could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in how I solved this problem, here is my approach:

1. In the model, I wrote a function that contains the logic to update all dependend fields from bar.
2. This function, I called in my views.py if the user changed bar. (Did this by checking the request content). If bar was changed, I saved bar and also called the function from 1
3. I needed coloring for the display. Because I reload (redirect to a success page that redirects back) the page every time I update values, I can use javascript for that. I parse the text from the fields in question and if they don't look like expected, I color them red. Else they are colored black.

So, basically I tried to break the problem into its pices: I need logic to update the field values, I need logic to know when to update the values, I need logic that colors.